# Trying to add hyperlinks to a Nav menu

Tags: html, css

I really like this navigation menu on Codepen.io, I like it but I'm not actually sure how to add hyperlinks to the menu. Can someone take a look at it for me? 
https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/wWVZAW?q=menu+with+mix&limit=all&type=type-pens

```
<div class='menu closed'><div class="logo"><img src="img/Menulogo.png" width="30" height="30"></div><div class='messages button'></div><div class='music button'></div><div class='home button'></div><div class='places button'></div><div class='bookmark button'></div><div class='main button'></div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your hyperlink around the `<div>` that represents the button.

```
<div class='menu closed'>
      <a href="url"><div class='messages button'></div></a>
      ...
    </div>
```

Comment: This solution works great but the link is only clickable in the upper portion of the circle that represents the button. How do I expand the clickable area?

Comment: @ChristopherBillups, I was able to expand the clickable box by adding CSS to the '<a>' tag. The problem I'm  having is that when I click the link, the menu closes instead of going to the link... Anyway, the below CSS should work.
a {
 display: block;
 height: 50%;
 width: 50%;
}